# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\lambda x \ln(1+x)+(1-\lambda) x \ln x}{x- \lambda \ln(1+x)+(1-\lambda)\ln x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Compute 
>   $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\lambda x \ln(1+x)+(1-\lambda) x \ln x}{x- \lambda \ln(1+x)+(1-\lambda)\ln x}$$ 
>   where $\lambda \in (0,1)$.

I tried using L'Hôpital's Rule, but the computations seem rather messy. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use L'Hôpital's Rule here, since, unless $\lambda=1$, that's *not* an indeterminate form. That limit is $0$, since it is of the form $\frac0\infty$. So, you only have to apply that rule when $\lambda=1$ and, in that case, it is not hard to see that the limit is $2$.